# How I can use a PHP code in C# desktop application

Tags: c#, php

Is there any way to run the PHP code on the c# app
since I'm working on an application that requires to implement of this [site's](https://smm-bomb.com/) API
but there is no documentation except for PHP, so is there any way I can use this piece of code in a c# application or convert this code in C# if that is possible.

```
public $api_url = 'https://smm-bomb.com/api/v2'; // API URL

public $api_key = ''; // Your API key

public function order($data) { // add order
    $post = array_merge(array('key' => $this->api_key, 'action' => 'add'), $data);
    return json_decode($this->connect($post));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to rewrite the call using C#, check docs if needed.
Another one is to made your custom `php-api` which wrap initial call.
Then from C# just use your `php-api`.
 `Postman` can be a useful tool to check your custom `php-api` and also for `C# code generation`

---custom php-api---

--update to fit `https://smm-bomb.com/api`--

```
<?php
class Api
{
    public $api_url = 'https://smm-bomb.com/api/v2'; // API URL
    public $api_key = '4a99333333333333333dummy'; // Your API key
...
//just copy-paste from example
}

//from-docs, create an instance an invoke any methods
//since it's a self contained class no imports required
//main 
$api = new Api();
$services = $api->services(); # return all services

$out = [];
//mainly here will be the return of api-call
$out["mykey"]="myvalue";
//output as json whatever wanted
$out["listServices"]=$services;
echo json_encode($out);
?>
//sample output
//{"mykey":"myvalue"}
```

This piece of code should be accessible via link eg: `https://yoursite/custom-api` (for security purpose can use a token on query-string. `/custom-api?key=123mykey` ->trivial approach)

Use `PostMan` to check and see code-generation

[image: C#]
[image: C#2]

Comment: Actually, I'm noob at php so can you provide any guide or useful link where I can get the help in this regard

Comment: Very bad for your side then. Me, I cannot teach in 5 minutes, week-months on required knowledge. Still, the answer will be updated with some more hints. Even trivial google search on some concepts can be very useful for start.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to learn basic concepts.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I do get the idea of how things work in the above example but can you u use my code as an example? Suppose this one  to get balance `public function balance() { // get balance
        return json_decode($this->connect(array(
            'key' => $this->api_key,
            'action' => 'balance',
        )));`
It will give me a better understanding.

Comment: call the function as usual and store the result into value. `$out["api-call"]=balance()`

Comment: in order to work need also to add all required imports in the file where the specific function is call (see from where is called and worked then add that file as import on top, eg: `require_once 'file_name.php'` or what ever is needed ). Have no idea what's on php side, if some sort of framework maybe it's an autoloader which will handle all import (maybe no need for additional import, but need to register the new file, etc). Anyway, `require_once` will fix the dependency.

Comment: Ohhh, you are right. I haven't noticed any import on documentation that is provided by the website. If you got time, can you look at this [link](https://smm-bomb.com/api) maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Doc is self-explanatory, just try it out and worked fine. Update the answer. Good Luck !